# Import database from phpmyadmin to webmin

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, webmin

im trying to import my wordpress db from cpanle's php my admin to webmin but it giving me :

```
/usr/bin/mysqlimport: Error: 1045, Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: YES), when using table:
```

i've done this before and it worked easily , and as you know i cant change my php my admin user name to my webmin user name cause php myadmin forces first part of username like this user_(custom)
anyone know what to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the detailed link to import to virtualmin a.k.a webmin

URL :: http://ucp.7l.com/knowledgebase/5/How-Do-I-ExportorBackup-a-MySQL-Database-in-Virtualmin.html

Before that you should have a sql import from phpmyadmin.

i.e, You should first export to a sql file from phpmyadmin then import it to webmin via the above link or please go through the steps below.

```
1.Log into your Virtual control panel
2.Select the domain that the MySQL database belongs to
3.Click on the Edit Databases link towards the left and then click import database.
```

Hope it helps

Comment: the problem was that i was importing my db from the third tab import form text file and i gave me that error now i imported it correctly